# importdata() function fails when page is re-loaded

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to have a self refreshing formula to import the latest data from a .csv saved in the same Google Drive location as the spreadsheet. The .csv I have set Share permissions so that "Anyone with the link can view".

I put the .csv's document id into cell A1 and use the formula:

```
=importdata("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id="&A1)
```

Which works fine while I have the document open (all columns and rows import correctly). If I close and reopen the sheet, another user opens the sheet, or some amount of time passes; the formula then gives an error:

[image: Error message]

> **Error**
> Could not fetch url:
> `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=...`

I have tried multiple modifications to the formulae used, and though I can get them to work, they always end up failing in the same way.

Comment: Have you tried using triggers and apps script to execute the importdata()?
I have found this issue on google support that has a workaround:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/15635541?hl=en&msgid=16402125

Comment: Even if I got that working (not possible unfortunately as my business account has Apps scripting disabled), it would not solve the issue in a way that meant the imported data never showed an error.

The imported data is displayed live on a public site, so even intermittent errors are far from ideal.

Comment: What happens when you put the link in a new tab in the browser?

Comment: The (Edge) tab closes itself and a download popup appears at the bottom of the screen with options for "Open", "Save ^", and "Cancel". Choosing "Open" results in the .csv file opening correctly.

Comment: Importrange is not for importing from csv, only for other sheets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `https://docs.google.com/` try usign `https://drive.google.com/`

The above because there are a lot of questions that use the later, but most imporant because the current domain of the service is `https://drive.google.com/`

Related

- [Displaying files (e.g. images) stored in Google Drive on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311092/1595451)
- [IMPORTDATA Google Sheet CSV on Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32473639/1595451)